# Divide something to make this factorial into "gapped" factorial?

Tags: polynomials

$(2n+1)!$ divide by what (in simple expression) can turn it into a "gapped" factorial: $1\times 3\times5\times\ldots\times(2n+1)$?

In other words,
how to turn $(2n+1)!$ to $1\times 3\times5\times\ldots\times(2n+1)$?

Comment: See [double factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide out the unwanted factors $2,4,6,\ldots, 2n$. As those are even, we actually divide out $2$ $n$ times and then $1,2,3,\ldots,n$. So you have
$$ \frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$$

Comment: How do you derive this result? Thanks.

Comment: I seem to get $\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^{n+2}\cdot n!}$ instead of $\frac{(2n+1)!}{2^n\cdot n!}$.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:   You want to find a way of expressing the numbers you want to remove.  the numbers you want to remove are $2 \times 4 \times 6 \times ... \times 2n$.   Is there something you can do to this expression to turn it into one that you know?

Comment: I struggle with this. Can you give me further hints?

Comment: Keep in mind this is a question about factorials.  Can you do something to the above expression to turn it into a factorial?